# How to make Checkboxes of Facebook Invite Friend dialog come checked?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

This Code Open the Invite Friend Dialog.

FB.ui({
  method: 'apprequests',
  message: 'My Great Request',
  display: 'iframe'
});

I need to make these checkbox come checked?

Answer (score 1):

Use the "to" parameter as mentioned in the [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/):

```
FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
      message: 'My Great Request',
      to: user_ids, 
    });
```

Comment: if i put these ids in 'to', they will come checked?

Comment: No, it will send to just those you specify.  But you could build your own selector dialog.  You can't have options pre-checked with that dialog.

Answer (score 0):

The user will need to click the checkbox to check them.

Comment: But is there a way to make them all checked?

Comment: hmmm, I thought I did tell you.  The user clicks each one.  When a checkbox is clicked it will toggle its state.